# Extending the interval of uniform convergence to end point

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Let $\{f_{n}:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}\}$ be a sequence of Riemann integrable functions which converges pointwise to a Riemann integrable function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. Now, suppose that $\{f_{n}\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $(a,b]$.

Q1) Under this hypothesis, is it possible to show that $\{f_{n}\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$? (without notions of measure theory)

Q2) More generally, under what conditions, the uniform convergence extends $(a,b]$ to $[a,b]$? I wonder if there is a simple case.

Please, let me know some advice or any reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N_1,N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$\sup_{x \in (a,b]} |f_n(x) -f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $n > N_1,$

and

$|f_n(a)-f(a)| <\epsilon$ for $n > N_2$

Comment: Ultimately you just need to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ when $n > N$ -- for every $x \in [a,b]$, i.e. $N$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: Choose $K\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $K>N_{2}$, and set $N=\max\{K,N_{1}\}$. Then, $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $n\ge N$ and $x\in[a,b]$. Is it correct?

Comment: @Primavera: Yes -  that is correct. You could simply choose $N = \max(N_1,N_2)$ as well.  It is just a matter of making the statement “... when $n > N$ ...” or “... when $n \geqslant N$ ...”

Comment: Thank you. The unintuitive tendency of the uniform convergence makes me think it's too hard.